# How to stop QGIS auto snapping new poly lines as they are being created?

Tags: qgis, line, snapping, map-editor

[image]

Im creating a polyline based data set which involves digistising around a large amount of street outlines. Is there a way to stop QGIS from auto snapping the new polyline section to a straight ahead bearing? See attached image for what I mean. The red line being the existing line section.

Comment: You could try switching **snapping** off by going to _Settings > Snapping options_ and change the "Snap to" setting to `OFF`.